# passing text From TableViewController to ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

sending text to label and number to int from tabelview to viewcontroller but it is not working

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    pushnavViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushnavViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    detailViewController.pushh.text = [IDNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.pushh.text = [listt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I also tried to do that , but not working :

```
detailViewController.pushh.text = [IDNum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.pushh.text = [listt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

i made all the property and synthesize them :

```
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *pushh;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *IDnumber;
```

so, any idea?

```
    NSArray *listt,*IDNum;
```

Comment: Is it pushing the view controller onscreen?

Comment: I guess the first things to check are whether IBNum and listt are not null and then that the two calls to objectAtIndex return something meaningful. And that detailViewController is not nil.

Comment: yes, it is pushing , but not changing the value of label

Comment: well, for one you are using `detailViewController.pushh.text` for both assignments.  Should be `detailViewController.IDnumber.text` for the first one, I believe.  Secondly, you can't change the .text property of the label until after the view is loaded.

Comment: share the code for `IDNum` and `listt`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one you are using `detailViewController.pushh.text` for both assignments.  Should be `detailViewController.IDnumber.text` for the first one, I believe.  Secondly, you can't change the `.text` property of the label until after the view is loaded.

Instead, create an `NSString` property and save your information to the `NSString`, then in your `viewDidLoad` method of you `pushnavViewController` assign the `label.text` with the value of the `NSString` property.